# Saving the state of my App through rotation

Tags: android

I am building a memory game app for a java class and i need to save which words are displayed through rotation of the device...the widgets that need to be saved and passed to the new onCreate() method are button widgets that i used setText to display the words that are being shown....can i save and pass the entire state of the application...here is my code that is obviously not working and i was hoping i could get some insight...thanks...here is my code..

```
private Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
.....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eight);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedInstanceState = myBundle;
    }
    ......
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
       myBundle = savedInstanceState;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the semantics of using the Bundle backwards.  You don't ever want to save the Bundle (or overwrite it).  Just use it to serialize your own state variables into it and out of it.  For example, if you want to preserve two integer variables and a string between a rotation (such that you can re-initialize the view with these members later), you could do the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eight);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {

        // Restore our member variables that represent activity state right here from the passed in Bundle.

        _x = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyApp.X", 0);
        _y = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyApp.Y", 0);
        _name = savedInstanceState.getString("MyApp.NAME", "player");

        // not shown - initializing the view elements with the initialized member variables.

    }
......

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // save our activity state by adding our member variables that represent activity state into the Bundle.
   savedInstanceState.putInt("MyApp.X", _x);
   savedInstanceState.putInt("MyApp.Y", _y);
   savedInstanceState.putString("MyApp.NAME", _name);

    // call the parent method *after* you have saved your state
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Bundle also supports arrays of simple types.

Comment: Tahnks for the reply I'm finally beginning to wrap my head around the whole idea.....

Comment: @GilSavage - Pick up the [BNRG book](http://www.amazon.com/Android-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321804333/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1430429519&sr=8-1&keywords=big+nerd+ranch+android).  It has a great tutorial on rotation and saving state between rotations.

Answer (score 0):

In method onSaveInstanceState add values which you want to save like below

```
@Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   savedInstanceState.putString("key","your string here");
}
```

and inside oncreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
     System.out.println(savedInstanceState .getString("key"));
  }

}
```